# CSS Flex, not limiting order of list items

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have managed to get this solution to change the order every 1, 2 etc.... so 1,3,2,5,4 but is there anyway to amend this so does not matter how many list items and more dynamic?

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}

li:nth-child(1),
li:nth-child(3) {
  order: -3;
}

li:nth-child(2),
li:nth-child(5) {
  order: -2;
}

li:nth-child(4),
li:nth-child(7) {
  order: -1;
}
```

```html
<h1>TEST 1:</h1>

<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
</ul>

<h1>TEST 2:</h1>

<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>12</li>
  <li>13</li>
  <li>14</li>
  <li>15</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: What exactly do you want? A few more details would help.

Comment: I want to automate the order, on desktop i have 2 columns of images which is 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9.10 etc.... which is 2x2, on mobile i do 1x1 but i want to swap the order so start with 1, then 3, then 2, then 5, then 4 etc...

Comment: See sample, which is like i have it, but need to make single column on mobile but change position on odd and even.... have a look here to see what imi trying to do https://www.ambientlounge.eu/collections/outdoor-bean-bags

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vgrd7oww/ - i have tried to do it manually but think got a few numbers wrong somewhere - can you have a look?

Comment: Consider taking a look under the hood of the website your referred. They don't use flexbox for re-arranging the grid. Their CSS uses floats and margins. But JavaScript may be your best bet. Check out: http://masonry.desandro.com/

Comment: If you want to apply logic in CSS then you should go for LESS or SASS

Comment: @NiteshRana No, Less and Sass are just for speeding up your CSS writing. It eventually has to compile to pure CSS. Any true "logic" would have to be supported at that pure CSS level.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> is there anyway to amend this so does not matter how many list items
>   and more dynamic?

If it's only the pattern you are looking for, where the image and text swap between left and right every 2:nd row, you can do that like this

```css
ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
ul li {
  display: flex;
  width: calc(50% - 10px);
  margin: 5px;
  background: lightgray;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
ul li:nth-child(4n+1) div:first-child,
ul li:nth-child(4n+2) div:first-child {
  order: 1;
}
ul li div:first-child {
  width: 66.66%;
  background: lightgreen;
  padding: 40px 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
ul li div:last-child {
  width: 33.33%;
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 40px 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  ul li {
    width: calc(100% - 10px);
  }
  ul li:nth-child(4n+1) div:first-child,
  ul li:nth-child(4n+2) div:first-child {
    order: 0;
  }
  ul li:nth-child(odd) div:first-child {
    order: 1;
  }
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li><div>1. image</div><div>text</div></li>
    <li><div>2. image</div><div>text</div></li>
    <li><div>3. image</div><div>text</div></li>
    <li><div>4. image</div><div>text</div></li>
    <li><div>5. image</div><div>text</div></li>
    <li><div>6. image</div><div>text</div></li>
    <li><div>7. image</div><div>text</div></li>
    <li><div>8. image</div><div>text</div></li>
    <li><div>9. image</div><div>text</div></li>
    <li><div>10. image</div><div>text</div></li>
    <li><div>11. image</div><div>text</div></li>
</ul>
```

---

If it should be as on the linked page, *Outdoor Bean Bags*, which have structured their items in groups of 4, then it will take a markup change, as shown in this sample

```css
div {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
div ul {
  width: 100%;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: flex-start;
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}
div ul li {
  display: flex;
  width: calc(50% - 10px);
  margin: 5px;
  background: lightgray;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
div ul li:nth-child(even),
div ul li:nth-child(odd) div:first-child {
  order: 1;
}
div ul li div:first-child {
  width: 66.66%;
  background: lightgreen;
  padding: 40px 10px;
  text-align: center;
}
div ul li div:last-child {
  width: 33.33%;
  background: lightblue;
  padding: 40px 10px;
  text-align: center;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  div ul li {
    width: calc(100% - 10px);
  }
  div ul li:nth-child(even) {
    order: 0;
  }
}
```

```html
<div>
  <ul>
    <li><div>1. image</div><div>text</div></li>
    <li><div>2. image</div><div>text</div></li>
    <li><div>3. image</div><div>text</div></li>
    <li><div>4. image</div><div>text</div></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li><div>5. image</div><div>text</div></li>
    <li><div>6. image</div><div>text</div></li>
    <li><div>7. image</div><div>text</div></li>
    <li><div>8. image</div><div>text</div></li>
  </ul>
  <ul>
    <li><div>9. image</div><div>text</div></li>
    <li><div>10. image</div><div>text</div></li>
    <li><div>11. image</div><div>text</div></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, great help! working on integrating and tweaking now however just noticed that desktop will be the wrong order... would need to be 1,2, 3, 4, 5, 6 etc... so 1 and 2, 3 and 4 etc... as your example it does 1,3, 2, 4 for desktop

Comment: @James Yes, the 2:nd sample does that, as that is how the linked site works. So can't you use my 1:st sample?

Comment: Opps maybe i used the 2nd version.... sorry mate, give me a min as just mocking up on jsfiddle and converted to SCSS

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vgrd7oww/1/ - any ideas what i missed out? Buttons not floating right way - i was settings left and right classes from admin image in alt tag but wanted to base on yours so did not have to use that and mobile does not seem to be changing order - Thanks for all your help on this, been a huge help!

Comment: @James You missed the `&.collection-hover ` class in the media query ... and it is needed or else the specificity will be lower and the rule won't apply

Comment: Done some tweaks, sorry its really late and brain clearly not working lol https://jsfiddle.net/vgrd7oww/7/ - few issues im facing, not snapping to the right order in mobile, button position not changing and also the hover text... this is because i removed the set classes left and right.. should i got back to that you think? just thought we could automate in CSS with this new code you have helped me with thats all. Again mate, thanks for your help in this.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141792/discussion-between-james-and-lgson).

Comment: Hi mate, been playing for ages and have it working but know why im getting issue... as setting the background image with does the left and right, when an even number will always show 2 so guess would need to separate

Comment: @James If you send the fiddle link I'll have a look

Comment: I found if it is a even number does not position all of them correctly as you can see here: https://jsfiddle.net/vgrd7oww/14/ - see here an odd amount shows fine: https://jsfiddle.net/vgrd7oww/13/ - it also does not seem to be poisoning correctly as on desktop it is: butterfly, twin, avatar, versa so assumed on mobile would be butterfly, avatar, twin, versa but if you look at fiddle 13 that is not the case... thanks for your help matey!

Comment: @James Will have a look later

Comment: Thanks mate, diamond!

Comment: @James Here is an [**updated fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/vLmmehhL/1/), based on my initial code, and where I added the same markup structure you have in yours. This works no matter how many items you use. Sorry I didn't worked it out from yours, I felt less distracted when I had to deal with something clean :) ... but it should be easy to apply this

Comment: Thanks mate, ill check it out and integrate changes into the development. Great on however many items it is, fingers crossed works on the imaged version and the order is more correct :) will keep you posted.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vgrd7oww/19/ - think applied ok, looking over changes but not ordering.... i guess to use your solution would need to separate the image itself and logo instead of being one background image... i assume thats why its happening?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/vLmmehhL/2/ - replaced html and yea was right that is why.... so guess thats the solution to make it clean and working well lol

Comment: actually if you make the output window winder it works fine on desktop, so surely we can snap on mobile to match up? just needs to reverse the item and swap positions of elements i guess? see what i mean?

Comment: @James If you study my [latest fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vLmmehhL/1/) you'll see how it works. As you have the logo and image as 1 picture (which I haven't noticed until now when you told me), it is of course not possible to swap logo/image, but what you can do is to use the logo part as background in the first div (blue) and the image in the right (green). That will make them shift with my short and simple code piece. So as long as you stay with that, it works on both desktop and mobile

Comment: Yea that was my assumption and working out to why it was not acting as it should from the JSFiddle - opacity: 0.5 showed me the way - its ok for now, but going to separate them so more fluid and dynamic. Thanks for your help and time on this.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this effect on any length of list via a short piece of javascript.

Beginning with the third list item...

- the script will take the **third list item** and place it before its predecessor
- it will then progress to the **fifth list item** and place it before its
  predecessor
- it will then progress to the **seventh list item** etc.

**Working Example:**

```js
var lists = document.getElementsByTagName('ul');

for (var i = 0; i < lists.length; i++) {
    
    var items = lists[i].getElementsByTagName('li');
    
    for (var j = 2; j < items.length; j = j + 2) {
        lists[i].insertBefore(items[j], items[(j-1)]);
    }
    
}
```

```css
div {
float: left;
width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
<h2>Test 1</h2>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div>
<h2>Test 2</h2>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>12</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div>
<h2>Test 3</h2>
<ul>
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li>4</li>
  <li>5</li>
  <li>6</li>
  <li>7</li>
  <li>8</li>
  <li>9</li>
  <li>10</li>
  <li>11</li>
  <li>12</li>
  <li>13</li>
  <li>14</li>
  <li>15</li>
  <li>16</li>
</ul>
</div>
```